# NSURLSessionDownloadTask created by AFNetworking does not resume after force quit

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using `AFURLSessionManager's` `downloadTaskWithRequest:progress:destination:completionHandler:` method to create a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`.

As far as I see, `AFURLSessionManager` implements `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` and sets itself as a delegate to the `NSURLSession` (that is also created by this manager).

When I force-quit the app during a download and relaunch it `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate's` `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` method should be called according to Apple's documentation.

But even I register a completion block to `AFURLSessionManager` by `setTaskDidCompleteBlock:` method (which is called to reflect that callback I mentioned above), the block is not executed at app relaunch. Actually I do not expect it to be called since the
NSURLSession instance has already died at the termination.

How should I accomplish this task? Namely I want to resume my download at app relaunch if user force quits the app.

Comment: If the user force quits the app, that will kill all requests (whether standard requests or background requests). If you want a request to continue after the the app terminates, you have to use background session, but IIRC, even those won't continue if the user force quits the app, only if the app left foreground and was jettisoned during the normal course of the lifespan of the app.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned in the comments, this is normal behavior.  Force-quitting an app causes all background requests to be canceled.  Tasks in a background session continue running *only* while your app is suspended or when your app is terminated by the OS (e.g. if the app crashes, or if another app uses so much memory that your app gets evicted).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I don't need the download continue on background after force quit. What I need is to store the resume-data at applicationWillTerminate event, so that I can resume the download when the user launches the app again. 
I tried to cancel the download and produced the resume data successfully in applicationWillTerminate callback but I couldn't save the data to a file. I think the time is not enough for this. What am I supposed to do to handle this situation?

Comment: It isn't a very large piece of data.  Try just tossing it into NSUserDefaults and calling synchronize.

Comment: I have tried that but wasn't working, and then I figured out why, If I run the application via xcode, forcing to quit creates an exception and applicationWillTerminate callback does not function properly. It works now, thanks.